# Easy Post API with Laravel

Tags: laravel, easypost

I am trying to use EasyPost with Laravel, but I don't know how to use it in laravel. 
I try to use it on my controller but I get an error

```
require_once("path/to/vendor/autoload.php");
\EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey('cueqNZUb3ldeWTNX7MU3Mel8UXtaAMUi');
```

Comment: How did you install it? via composer?

Comment: `require_once("path/to/vendor/autoload.php");` should contain the actual path to `autoload.php`. So, it should be something like `require_once("/home/user/code/vendor/autoload.php");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you running this in your laravel application and installed this via composer the autoloading should be already active.. you can remove that require_once line